# angular 2 how to sum column ngFor

Tags: angular

trying to understand how to sum the column from table, every  is added with *ngFor ( like todo-list), i wanna sum one of column, how i can do it in angular 2 ? 
So i have table like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
    <td>{{item.num1 }}</td>
    <td>{{item.num2}}</td>
    <td>{{item.num3}}</td>
    <td>{{item.num4}}</td>
    <td>{{item.num5}}</td>
</tr>
```

and I need to sum all that columns below like:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items">
     <td>{{item.num1 }}</td>
     <td>{{item.num2}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num3}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num4}}</td>
     <td>{{item.num5}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td>SUM1</td>
     <td>SUM2</td>
     <td>SUM3</td>
     <td>SUM4</td>
     <td>SUM5</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Sum in TS code and show it using binding. `*ngFor` doesn't sum.

Comment: It seems straight forward, what did you try

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would have to create a getSum(index: number): number method in your Angular 2 Component class, something like this:

```
getSum(index: number) : number {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
    sum += this.items[i][index];
  }
  return sum;
}
```

and in your html, replace your SUMX by:

```
<td>{{ getSum(0) }} </td><td>{{ getSum(1) }}</td> ...
```

And you could of course also use a ngFor to create the multiple td tags if needed.

[EDIT]: to have the exact code you need based on your fiddle:

```
  getSum(column) : number {
    let sum = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
      sum += this.list[i][column];
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

and in html:

```
<td>{{ getSum('newInput') }}</td><td>{{ getSum('newOutput') }}</td>
```

[EDIT 2]: just for completeness, you can also do the sum of an array using the reduce function rather than using a loop in the getSum method:

```
var sum = this.items[i]['myfield'].reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; }, 0);
```

Comment: i did it, but there is empty field now

Comment: Did you use the this keyword ? this.items ? It seems you are not accessing the right property. The example this.items[i][index] works if you have a matrix (ex: items: number[][]).

Comment: here is my code, i guess its a little easily to understand : https://fiddle.jshell.net/x8d6mh6n/

Comment: You forgot the i index in line 51. But, ok, from your code, replace the getSum function by:

getSum(column) : number {
  let sum = 0;
  for(let  i = 0; i < this.list.length; i++) {
    sum += this.list[i][column];
  }
  return sum;
}

if you call getSum('newInput'), you will have the sum for column 'newInput'

Comment: am, in last column there is code: <td>{{0.05*item.newInput || 0.05*item.newOutput}}</td> how i can sum this column ?

Comment: not entirely sure what you mean. Do you want <td>{{ 0.05*item.newInput + 0.05*item.newOutput}}</td> ?

Comment: yeah exactly ) im trying to put that (0.05*item.newInput ) in ts, but yet cant ))

Comment: Hi @Laurent-PhilippeAlbou can you help with this question [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210788/how-to-get-sum-of-columns-that-have-strings-and-numbers-in-typescript-and-call-i), I have an array of object, looping over this, I get an Object, which won't have any index

Answer (score 1):

```
getSum(): number {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
      sum += this.items[i].num1;
    }
    return sum;
  }
```

Comment: Copying a code block from another answer and posting it as a unique answer doesn't help anyone.  How does this question provide a better solution than the answer you copied the code from?

Comment: this.items[i].num1; take note of the dot operator to access the required field. The provided answer uses a matrix format. Which was giving me an error.