# Get total of single column at the end

Tags: angular

I have a creating the grid and at last I need the total of looping column at the end

```
<tr *ngFor="let racklist of racklists">
 <span style="display:none;">{{racklist.billedhour}}</span>
</tr>
<tr>
  Total
</tr>
```

Please review below table be like

Billed Hours

```
 0.40
 0.40
 10.0
 12.0
```

Total should come as 22.80

Comment: Please add your racklist data

Comment: Check out the answer here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45467550/angular-2-how-to-sum-column-ngfor>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a function to calculate the total and return the total.

```
getTotal(){
  return this.racklists.reduce((a, b) => +a + +b.billedhour, 0);
}
```

and call the function

```
<tr>
  {{getTotal()}}
</tr>
```

Comment: its responding me as NaN

Comment: hi the total is coming well but it is showing 20.8 instead of 20.80. Can you tell me how to show 2 decimal after dot

Comment: can you answer me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076422/how-to-count-length-of-list-having-read-as-true

Comment: posted answer there