# How to count length of list having read as true

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have one list as

```
let chats: Chats[] = [
{id: 1, name: "James Anderson",read=false},
{id: 2, name: "James Anderson",read=true},
{id: 3, name: "James Anderson",read=true},
{id: 4, name: "James Anderson",read=true},
]
```

and on cshtml page I used to right as {{chats.length}} which return all the count but I need to return the count whose read value is set as false

i.e I need the count as 1 instead of 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array.filter and length as follows,

```
let result  = chats.filter(t=>!t.read).length;
```

**DEMO**

```js
var chats = [
{id: 1, name: "James Anderson",read:false},
{id: 2, name: "James Anderson",read:true},
{id: 3, name: "James Anderson",read:true},
{id: 4, name: "James Anderson",read:true}
];

let result = chats.filter(t=>!t.read).length;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you answer this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54218670/in-devextreme-popup-assignedto-data-is-not-coming