# How to get Sum of columns that have Strings and Numbers in typescript and call it in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I get the sum of only numbers in a column that has both numbers and strings? The data is being pulled from an api and being populated on a table. I have simple code that gets the sum, but due to the combination of both numbers and strings I end up with NaN as the result.

I have tried to check for NaN but I get empty result

```
 getSum(index: number) : number {
    let sum = 0;
    let i = 0;
    if( isNaN(i) == true){
      for(let i = 0; i < this.agemenBaisv.length; i++) {
        sum += this.agemenBaisv[i][index];
      }
      return sum;
    }
  }
```

when I do it this way I end up wit NaN

```
getSum(index: number) : number {
    let sum = 0;
    let i = 0;
    if( isNaN(i)){
      for(let i = 0; i < this.agemenBaisv.length; i++) {
        sum += this.agemenBaisv[i][index];
      }
      return sum;
    }
  }
```

How can I wrap it in such a way that, it calculates only numbers  and skips strings?

Comment: `if( isNaN(i) == true)` and `if(isNaN(i))` will both *only* continue if the number zero (the value of `i` at the start) is considered Not a Number. That's never the case, so you'd never get into the loop. `getSum` should always be producing `undefined`.

Comment: Also, if you use `+` on a number and a string, you don't get `NaN` - you get a string back. It's unclear what the issue is here.

Comment: Hi @VLAZ thank you for your response, I keep on getting NaN when I try to do the sum, How can I only calculate and get the sum of the numbers only?

Comment: `this.agemenBaisv.forEach(x=>{ sum=sum+((x==+x)?(+x):0)})`

Comment: Hi @Eliseo thank you for your feedback ,am more confused, can you show me how to implement it, i end up with `this condition will always return 'false' since the types 'AgeDisplacement' and 'number' have no overlap.`

Comment: sorry, I don't take account how your variable agemenBaisv is, I try to response in an answer, really is replace your condition isNaN

Answer (score 0):

the idea is use "+" to convert a string in number. Remember that, e.g.

- if variable="4" +variable==variable is true,
- if variable=2 +variable==variable is true,
- if variable="a" +variable==variable is false,

So:

```
getSum(index: number) : number {
    let sum = 0;
    this.agemenBaisv.forEach(x=>{
         sum+=(+x[index]==x[index]?(+x[index]):0)
    })
    return sum;
  }
```

Comment: Hi @Eliseo this removes NaN on the row, but now I end up with zeros on all columns that have values

Answer (score 0):

```
const sum = [1, 2, 3, 'a', '1'].reduce((accumaltedValue, currentValue) => {
    return accumaltedValue + (Number(currentValue) !== NaN ? 0 : Number(currentValue));
});

console.log(sum)
```

If i understand you correctly this is what you want to do. Take a list of numbers and strings and reduce them down to a sum right. here is how reduce is used: [enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0):

The [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method of arrays is one to know and love. It solves a lot of problems.

Here I've got two solutions.

- The first takes the array and calls reduce once to remove all of the elements that are not numbers, by the strictest definition. In the sample data here, it does not count `'3'` as a number. The second reduce call is the one that does the actual summation.
- The second takes the array and tries to parse each element as a number. If that is successful, the parsed value is added to the array; otherwise, it is left out. The same second reduce call is used to do the summation.

Both of them use the [spread syntax for arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_array_literals) to keep the code concise.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 'a', '3'];
function sumIgnoringStrings(arr) {
  return arr.
    reduce((agg, cur) => 
      [
        ...agg, 
        ...(typeof cur === 'number' ? [cur] : [])
      ], 
      []).
    reduce((agg, cur) => agg + cur, 0);
}
function sumParseStrings(arr) {
  return arr.
    reduce((agg, cur) => 
      [
        ...agg, 
        ...(!isNaN(parseFloat(cur)) ? [parseFloat(cur)] : [])
      ], 
      []).
    reduce((agg, cur) => agg + cur, 0);
}
console.log(sumIgnoringStrings(data));
console.log(sumParseStrings(data));
```